# laravel + mongo + gpaphql get children array

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, graphql

i have data in mongodb
it is a road object that has a property and an array of points that it consists of:

[image: mongo sheme]

my  model in laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Traits\Uuids;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Road extends Eloquent
{
    //use HasFactory;
    use Uuids;

    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'roads';

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'roadId', 'code', 'name', 'points'];

    #public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function fields() : array
    {
        return [
            'id' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'The identifier of the road',
            ],
            'roadId' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::int()),
                'description' => 'ID road of external database',
            ],
            'code' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'code of document',
            ],
            'name' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'road name',
            ],
            'points' => [
                'name' => 'points',
                'description' => 'points of road',
                'type' => GraphQL::type('RoadPoints'),
                'is_relation' => false
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

here we refer to a new type of "point on the road"

GraphQL type 'RoadPoints':

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Types;

use App\Models\Address;
use App\Models\RoadPoints;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Type as GraphQLType;

class RoadPointsType extends GraphQLType
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name'          => 'RoadPoints',
        'description'   => 'The points is defined by the format GeoJSON Point',
        'model'         => RoadPoints::class,
    ];

    public function fields(): array
    {
        return [
            'type' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'The format GeoJSON',
            ],
            'pk' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'piket of point',
            ],
            'coordinates' => [
                'type' =>  Type::listOf(GraphQL::type('GeoJSON')),
                'description' => 'The partner lat and lng',
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

laravel model of RoadPoints

model RoadPoints class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class RoadPoints extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = ['type', 'pk', 'coordinates'];

    protected $casts = [
        'coordinates' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

graphql RoadQuery :

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;

use App\Models\Road;
use Closure;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Query;
use App\Services\RoadService;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;

class RoadQuery extends Query
{
    private $roadService;

    public function __construct(RoadService $roadService)
    {
        $this->roadService = $roadService;
    }

    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'Road',
        'description' => 'Query to Road data and points.'
    ];

    public function type(): Type
    {
        return Type::listOf(GraphQL::type('Road'));
    }

    public function args(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => ['name' => 'id', 'type' => Type::string()],
            'roadId' => ['name' => 'roadId', 'type' => Type::int()],
            'code' => ['name' => 'code', 'type' => Type::string()],
            'name' => ['name' => 'name', 'type' => Type::string()],
            'lat' => ['name' => 'lat', 'type' => Type::float()],
            'lng' => ['name' => 'lng', 'type' => Type::float()]
        ];
    }

    public function resolve($root, $args, $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo, Closure $getSelectFields)
    {
        $fields = $resolveInfo->getFieldSelection($depth = 3);

        return $this->roadService->find($args, $fields);
    }
}
```

result:

[image: graphql not found pk + coordinates]

why pk and coordinates is null ?
Please tell me how to correctly select all objects in the array (points).

Answer (score 0):

error in model

change

```
'type' => GraphQL::type('RoadPoints'),
```

to

```
'type' => Type::listOf(GraphQL::type('RoadPoints')),
```